# Hibernate List-index occassionally getting null value

Tags: hibernate

I have this mapping in my hbm.xml file.  But for some strange reasong I am getting occassional null values on SEQUENCE column.  How to restrict it from being set to null?
I cannot use Set in the mapping since i need to index my categories.

```
    <list name="categories" table="CATEGORY" cascade="save-update, delete" lazy="false"      outer-join="false">
            <key column="ID" />
            <list-index column="SEQUENCE"/> 
            <one-to-many class="Category"/>
```

Comment: have you mapped the column sequence to a property in Category too?